# Having trouble with passing over image files to celery worker

Tags: python, django, celery

I'm making a `Django api server` for an app.
Concept of the app is a photo diary and an user can upload diary(a post) with many photos.(ForeignKey related)
The api server handles image files, so I use `VersatileImageField`, django third-party module, for the imagefield.

The client can request with many image files, so I want to use `Celery` for the image handlings. To Celery worker, I pass over `django.core.files.uploadedfile.InMemoryUploadedFile`(File)s and an ID of an instance of a model.

But when I pass `File`, there is an error

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode 
byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
```

So my new strategy is
1. Use python `base64`  module and encode the image file and overwrap the `File`
2. Send over image `File` to the celery worker
3. The task decode the `File` and make a Image instance with it.

Here is the serializer create method for passing over `File` to the task.

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    photos_data = list(validated_data.pop('photo_set'))
    for photo in photos_data:
        # photos_data is the list of `InMemoryUploadedFile`
        # Encoding image file 
        encoded_photo = base64.b64encode(photo.read())
        photo.seek(0)
        photo.truncate()
        photo.write(encoded_photo)
        photo.seek(0)


    post = Post.objects.create(
        **validated_data,
    )

    # celery task
    task_upload_photos.delay(photos_data=photos_data, post_id=post.id)

    return post
```

And the task is like this

```
@shared_task
def task_upload_photos(photos_data, post_id):
    post = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)

    if photos_data:
        for photo in photos_data:
            decoded_photo = base64.b64decode(photo.read())
            photo.seek(0)
            photo.truncate()
            photo.write(decoded_photo)
            photo.seek(0)
            Photo.objects.create(post=post, photo=photo)

            photo.close()
        return {'Message': 'Photos are created.'}
    else:
        return {'Message': 'No photos delivered.'}
```

Yes it's not that cool, I think. I've searched other posts and many say
`only send instances' id, not instances' themselves`.
But I think this solution would work well with no problems. However when I make Photos and try to retrieve them, another exception is raised.

```
OSError at /posts/post_list/111/ cannot identify image file 
<File: `path`/media/photo/photo/asdf_0sbMULC.jpg>
```

It says it cannot identify decoded image `File` and
I really want to why the error is raised.

I printed out `type` and `len` of image files before sending and after encoding and decoding each and they're same.

Am I missing something? Please give me some advice.
Why there was OS Error and can't read it as image files.
Thank you

Comment: I'm thinking the problem you've run into is just that `InMemoryUploadedFile` cannot be cleanly serialized. Hard to tell because your question is a bit fragmentary. Having the entire stack trace of the errors you get would help.